# Adding offset to all elements in a structure

Tags: c

Is there a way to add an offset to all elements in a structure in one go.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date {           /* global definition of type date */
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

main()
{

    struct date  today;

    today.month = 10;
    today.day = 14;
    today.year = 1995;

    //I want to add 2 to month/day/year.
    today.month += 2;
    today.day += 2;
    today.year += 2;

    printf("Todays date is %d/%d/%d.\n", \
        today.month, today.day, today.year );
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I wanted to know a better approach of how to set the values of all elements in a struct, rather than setting them individually.

Comment: Turn it into a function and pass an argument in?

Comment: `int *array[] = {&today.month, &today.day, &today.year}; for (int i=0;i<3;i++) *array[i]+=2;` In other words, "NO", but that was too short for a comment.

Comment: If the struct only contains elements of the same type, you could iterate through them with a pointer loop.

Comment: Yes all the elements are of same type int.

Comment: What possible reason could you have to do this with a date structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok let me start of with a disclaimer: this is definitely bad style and I don't know why you would want to do it.

Key points:

1. This only works if all the elements in the struct are of the same type
2. This will work for arbitrarily many attributes of the same type in the struct
3. This might not work at all due to padding between members. I doubt it is likely, but it is not guaranteed by the C standard.
4. Why not just make a method to do it?
5. Did I mention this is bad style?

Have fun:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <assert.h>

    struct date {
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
    };


    int main() {
        struct date d;
        d.month = 10;
        d.day = 14;
        d.year = 1995;
        printf("Before\n\tm: %d, d: %d, y: %d\n", d.month, d.day, d.year);
        size_t numAttributes = 3;
        assert(sizeof(struct date) == numAttributes*sizeof(int));
        for(int i = 0; i < numAttributes; ++i) {
            int *curr = (int *)((char *)&d + i*sizeof(int));   // memory address of current attribute.
            *curr += 2;                                                 // how much you want to change the element
        }
        printf("After\n\m: %d, d: %d, y: %d\n", d.month, d.day, d.year);
        return 0;
```

Output:

```
Before
    Month: 10, Day: 14, Year: 1995
After
    Month: 12, Day: 16, Year: 1997
```

Wash your hands thoroughly after you're done.

Comment: There could be padding bytes between the members of the `struct`, to be portable you need to calculate the `offsetof` of each member as you do with `month`

Comment: @AlterMann There wouldn't be padding if they are of the same type no?

Comment: It's unlikely but C doesn't guarantee it:  6.7.2.1(15): A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. **There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.
 Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in an implementation- defined manner appropriate to its type.**

Comment: @AlterMann I thought that might be an issue, but since the implementation of the padding is to fix the bit alignments, it wouldn't make sense to pad objects of the same type. I'll add a disclaimer to my code saying this is dangerous (as if I haven't discouraged doing this enough already :p )

Comment: As a protection I suggest: `assert(sizeof(struct date) == sizeof(int) * 3);` before the `for` loop, or better yet, if your are under C11 you can check this on compile time with: `static_assert(sizeof(struct date) == sizeof(int) * 3, "Change your compiler bro");`